# Velocity controller does not stop on Slopes

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working with ROS Kinetic and Gazebo 7 in a vehicle model.

To simplify things, the model has 4 continuous joints to apply a certain velocity to the model. With the `<transmissions>` tag I linked the joints in gazebo with a `velocity_controller` interface from ROS_control. In a planar environment the controller just works fine, the problem comes when I test the controllers on terrain with slopes. The vehicle model is huge and has a high mass value (2000 Kg), and that may be the problem.

If I input, let's say and X velocity to the controller, it is unable to reach the target velocity. And it get worse when the model is in a slope and I command it to stop (0 velocity), because the model is unable to stop having always a very small velocity that moves the model very slowly in Gazebo.

I tried to adjust the pid gains of `gazebo_ros_control` but always with the same effect depending on the environment: The higher the slope is the more velocity error It outputs.

I am just wondering if there is a way to decrease error in this environment of there are similar problems or works in this community.

I will post here the config file for controllers:

```
joint_state_controller:
 type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
 publish_rate: 50

control_vel:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
    joints:
      - front_left_wheel_joint
      - back_left_wheel_joint
      - front_right_wheel_joint
      - back_right_wheel_joint

/gazebo_ros_control:
  pid_gains:
      front_left_wheel_joint:
          p: 2000.0
          i: 0.0
          d: 0.0

      back_left_wheel_joint:
          p: 2000.0
          i: 0.0
          d: 0.0

      front_right_wheel_joint:
          p: 2000.0
          i: 0.0
          d: 0.0

      back_right_wheel_joint:
          p: 2000.0
          i: 0.0
          d: 0.0
```

And the joint description:

```
<joint name="wheel_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="cont_wheel"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy = "0 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <limit effort="1000" velocity="20"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.1" friction="0.1"/>
  <joint_properties damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
  <safety_controller k_velocity="200"/>   
</joint>

<transmission name="wheel_joint_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_joint_motor">
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336068/velocity-controller-does-not-stop-on-slopes/) by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1695 on 2019-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-24**:
Just a note: [velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/cb3c6cb66a2910e20cfcbc152b21e3c7e2e0cc19/velocity_controllers/include/velocity_controllers/joint_group_velocity_controller.h#L46-L60) is a *forwarding command* controller. It's `in => out`. There is no actual control loop there. So PID values are ignored.

If you want / need a closed-loop controller, you'll have to either switch your vehicle to an effort interface and use [effort_controllers/JointVelocityController](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/cb3c6cb66a2910e20cfcbc152b21e3c7e2e0cc19/effort_controllers/include/effort_controllers/joint_velocity_controller.h#L39-L60), or you could create a customised version ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-24**:
..  using the [ClosedLoopHardwareInterfaceAdapter](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/24191346c909769cd02d8041bd83fcd9c83e294e/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/hardware_interface_adapter.h#L134-L142).

> I tried to adjust the pid gains of `gazebo_ros_control` but always with the same effect depending on the environment: The higher the slope is the more velocity error It outputs.

are you referring to the `p`, `i` and `d` values in your `.yaml` configuration? As I wrote above, those are not used by the `JointGroupVelocityController` that you're using.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-10-25**:
Hi @gvdhoorn,

Thanks for your answer. I decided to implement a new controller to have a close loop. The problem is that Gazebo is always reporting a small velocity on the joint and I am unable to control the platorm in a planar ground.

Besides, I do not understand the difference betweern the `gazebo_ros_control` pid gains and the `effort_controller` pid gains. I can confirm the pid gains defined in the file I posted are used by gazebo to output new velocity commands because depending on the values I assing there, I have different velocity output for the joint.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-26**:
Gazebo runs PID controllers itself, internally, depending on how the `hardware_interface` interfaces with Gazebo itself.

I don't know how that is implemented. But I can definitely state that PID gains are not used at all by fowarding command controllers (ie: those in `ros_controllers`).

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-10-26**:
Ok, I am going to try to implement a custom controller knowing this.

Thanks..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-26**:
Is there anything preventing you from switching your simulated vehicle to an effort interface? That would seem to offer a way forward without requiring any custom code. You'd just have to switch the Gazebo description to an effort `hardware_interface` and use `effort_controllers/JointVelocityController` in your `gazebo_ros_control` configuration.

If your response is going to be: but my actual hw only has a velocity interface, then I don't think that would matter, depending on the level at which you are simulating your vehicle.

In the end the controllers should bring your vehicle to a desired velocity, exactly as it would when using the `hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface` it would seem to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @gvdhoorn,

Sorry for the late response, I did not need to change my controllers type, I just needed to tune properly the PID gains I was using.

Whit the parameters properly set I managed to control the platform in every instance.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-05**:\

> I just needed to tune properly the PID gains I was using.

which gains specifically? Those of your `ros_control` controller, or the ones used by Gazebo?

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-11-05**:
I adjusted the ones used by the `gazebo_ros_control` pkgs. Internally they are used to control each joint.